# Accelerometer logger: experiencing occasional long delays between frames

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am writing an app that logs the accelerations of the mobile phone every 40ms (at 25Hz). This frame rate can be held on average, but sometimes I am experiencing delays of 5'000ms - 50'000ms between timeframes. I am wondering why this happens.

Here you have a graph of the delays where you can see that they occur quite often:

[image: occasional long delays between accelerometer measurements]

Here's what I am doing (which might be bad):

- The activity points to a accelerometer logger class (singleton, pure java, no android class extensions).
- The accelerometer logger singleton continues to log in the background.
- The accelerometer logger saves every log directly to the sqlite db.
- I am also logging GPS data in the background.
- The DAO (Data Access Object) assigns every Log to a LinkedBlockingQueue and saves them in a separate thread.

Here's what I think might be the problem:

- Maybe i have to implement further lifecycle methods, or extend a specific android class, so that the accererometer logger gains priority (or just set the priority somewhere).
- I might use the `event.timestamp` instead of `System.currentTimeMills()`. (I would prefer not to do this, as some sensors have different timezones, thats why i use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but if necessary I'd switch.)

Do you have any experience with this or suggestions where the problem could probably lie?

Here's my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class AccelerometerLogger implements SensorEventListener {

    private static AccelerometerLogger singleton = new AccelerometerLogger();

    private LoggerDao loggerDao;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    private Sensor accelerometer;

    private double acceleorometerRate = 25; // Hz

    int accelerometerDelayMicroseconds = (int) (Math.round(((1/this.acceleorometerRate)*1000000.0)));

    private AccelerometerLogger()
    {
        this.loggerDao = LoggerDao.getInstance();
    }

    public static AccelerometerLogger getInstance()
    {
        return singleton;
    }

    public void start(Context context)
    {
        this.sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        this.accelerometer = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        int accelerometerMinDelay = this.accelerometer.getMinDelay();

        //Log.d("lggr-r", "desired delay: "+this.accelerometerDelayMicroseconds+" microseconds");
        //Log.d("lggr-r", "provided min delay: "+accelerometerMinDelay+" microseconds");

        if(accelerometerMinDelay < this.accelerometerDelayMicroseconds)
        {
            this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.accelerometer, this.accelerometerDelayMicroseconds);
            //Log.d("lggr-r", "listener registered for desired rate: "+this.acceleorometerRate+"Hz (delay of "+this.accelerometerDelayMicroseconds+" microseconds).");
        } 
        else if(accelerometerMinDelay==0)
        {           
            this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            // Log.d("lggr-r", "listener registered for streaming api. only changes will be notified (interrupt).");
        }
        else
        {
            int providedRate = (int) Math.round(1 / (accelerometerMinDelay / 1000000.0));
            this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            // Log.d("lggr-r", "can't read at the desired rate ("+this.acceleorometerRate+"Hz), app will read at "+providedRate+"Hz instead (delay of "+accelerometerMinDelay+" microseconds).");
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        this.sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
    {
        // String name = sensor.getName();
        // Log.d("lggr", "the accurracy of "+name+" changed to "+accuracy+".");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        // lazy load loggerDao (TODO: fix all of those)
        if(this.loggerDao == null)
        {
            this.loggerDao = LoggerDao.getInstance();
        }


        String values = "";
        for(float value : event.values) values += value+",";
        values = values.substring(0,values.length()-2);

        // long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Log.d("lggr", "acc = {time:"+timestamp+", data: ["+values+"]}");

        AccelerometerSample accelerometerSample = new AccelerometerSample();
        accelerometerSample.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        accelerometerSample.setValues(event.values);

        this.loggerDao.save(accelerometerSample);
    }

}
```

Apparently the problem only happens on the Samsung Galaxy SIII mini. I've tested it with a Samsung Galaxy SII (custom ROM) and the delays were always about 0.04s (ranging between 0.005 and 0.12s - much better).

Do you have any suggestions why this happens on the Samsung Galaxy SIII mini?

**UPDATE:**

Ben Voigts answer which purposed to use the `event.timestamp` has improved the delays significantly. Still, i am experiencing sometimes some longer delays. Do you know how I can further improve them?

[image]

Comment: can you post your sensor manager code

Comment: sure, i just added it.

Comment: It could be because of the logging. Log the data in a thread.

Comment: i tried accelerometer with 50 Hz, and i got variation from 50 to 39 Hz,but mostly its around 48 to 50 and once it went to 39 Hz. You can try in other hardware.

Comment: how long did you log? did you persist the data somewhere?

Comment: I just implemented the persistence in a separate thread. The data is now first pushed into a LinkedBlockingQueue. Still, that hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: Since this thread has more than a year and I have very similar problem which I aksed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302645/android-accelerometer-sampling-rate-delay-stabilization. I wonder @ndrizza if you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely should be using `event.timestamp`.  If you want local time, calculate the adjustment factor between `event.timestamp` and `System.currentTimeMills()` on the first event, and apply the same adjustment to subsequent samples.

The whole point of a hardware-provided timestamp attached to the sample is that it isn't messed up by thread scheduling delays.

Comment: That made the delays a lot shorter. They still spike like in my example above, and there are still regular large delays until 0.18s (compared to 0.04s) - but hat's already much better. Do you have an idea how I could further improve this?

Comment: @ndrizza: The hardware probably has a FIFO buffer which can hold a limited number of samples while waiting for the software to come collect them.  Normally it's the job of the driver to handle an interrupt when that FIFO is nearly full, and move the samples to a larger buffer in system memory.  If you're seeing multi-second skips, that is probably more than the driver buffer can handle, so increasing the priority of your thread may help make sure you read the samples before the buffer overflows.

Comment: Since your problem is worse on a particular device or ROM, it may be that the hardware FIFO is smaller, or the driver doesn't buffer data, or both.  I would try other ROMs on the device with poor performance and try to see whether the issue is hardware or software (of course, different ROMs don't necessarily use different driver versions)

Comment: Ultimately, your problem is that you're using the sensor for something that wasn't intended by the phone manufacturer.  They just want to know orientation in order to rotate the screen, and if the device is too busy to rotate the screen, what is the advantage to low latency detecting the orientation change?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very helpful answer! Can you tell me if Andorids SystemClock would be an equally good alternative to event.timestamp? Would be nice if this would save me the ajdusting, as I'm logging various sensors simultaneously which all to be recorded on a synchronous timescale.

Comment: @ndrizza: Wouldn't SystemClock miss the whole point, because you wouldn't be able to read it until you start processing in software?  The advantage of the `event.timestamp` is that the timestamp is generated in hardware at the time the event occurs, so it doesn't matter whether there is some delay before the software looks at it, the timestamp is preserved.

Comment: You are right. Moreover SystemClock doesn't perform much better than System.currentTimeMillis().

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Voigt said, it's necessary to use the event.timestamp in order to get accurate timestamps for the sensor measurements. Here's a code sample I've used myself and worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (sampleCounter == 0) {
        long miliTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long nanoTime = event.timestamp;

        timeDiff = miliTime - nanoTime / 1000000;
        log.info("Synchornizing sensor clock. Current time= " + miliTime
                + ", difference between clocks = " + timeDiff);
    }

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    long ts = event.timestamp / 1000000 + timeDiff;

    //Do your stuff

    sampleCounter++;
}
```